# Bad conversion of arguments in a function using struct

Tags: c, function, struct, arguments

I'm starting to learn C. I have a problem in a function who eventually will ask for a data for a new client, I'm doing like a agenda to practice a little, the problem is the compiler gives me an error:

```
**cannot convert `char*' to `agenda*' for argument `1' to `void introducir_datos(agenda*)'**
```

Seems everything its ok except this part I'm afraid it's a problem of char to char int to int etc.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct agenda {
    char   nombre[20];
    char   apellido[20];
    char   direccion[20];
    int    edad;
    int    telefono;
};

int credenciales(char login[20],char password[20]);
void introducir_datos (struct agenda cliente[30]);


int main(void){
    int x=0;
    int menu, comp, submenu;
    char login[20], password[20], cliente[30];

    puts("\nBienvendio a la agenda en C\n");
    puts("\nQue quieres hacer?\n");
    puts("1)Zona de administracion\n2)Listar productos\n3)Salir\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &menu);
    switch(menu){
        case 1:
            puts("\nBienvenido a la introduccion de datos\n");
            puts("\nAntes de nada comprobaremos tus credenciales\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            while (comp != 1){
                puts("\nLogin?\n");
                scanf("%s", &login);
                puts("\nPassword?\n");
                scanf("%s", &password);
                comp=credenciales(login,password);
            }
            puts("\nBienvenido a la zona admin\n");
            puts("\n1) Introduccir clientes\n2)Listar clientes\n3)Borrar clientes\n4)Salir\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &submenu);
            switch(submenu){
                case 1:
                    introducir_datos(cliente);
                    break;
            }
    }
}

int credenciales(char login[20],char password[20]){
    int comp;

    if ((strcmp(strlwr(login),"12345") == 0) && (strcmp(strlwr(password),"admin") == 0)){
        return comp = 1;
    }
    else {
        return comp = 0;
    }
}

void introducir_datos(struct agenda cliente[30]){
    char con[3];
    int x;

    while (!strstr(con,"si")){
        puts("\nDime su nombre\n");
        scanf("%s", &cliente[x].nombre);
        puts("\nDime su apellido\n");  
        scanf("%s", &cliente[x].apellido);
        puts("\nDime su direccion\n");
        scanf("%s", &cliente[x].direccion);
        puts("\nDime su edad\n");
        scanf("%d", &cliente[x].edad);
        puts("\nDime su telefono\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &cliente[x].telefono);
        x++;
        puts("\nQuieres seguir?\n");
        gets(con);
        strlwr(con);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Improvement: 1) in `introducir_datos(()`, replace `"%s"` with `"%19s"` to prevent buffer overflow.  2) never use `gets()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `introducir_datos()` is declared as follows:

```
void introducir_datos (struct agenda cliente[30]);
```

But in your nested `switch` statement, you have this line:

```
introducir_datos(cliente);
```

where `cliente` is declared as `char cliente[30]`. So instead of providing `introducir_datos()` with a `struct agenda*` argument, you are giving it a `char*` argument.

---

### Clarification:

The function `introducir_datos()` expects to be given an array of 30 `struct agenda` items as its argument.

This means that the argument type is `struct agenda*`, because you are sending a pointer to the first item in the array. (This is just how arrays work in C.)

You can't call this function with a `char[]` array as the argument, because a `char[]` array consists of `char` variables. A `char` doesn't have any `nombre`, `apellido`, `direccion`, `edad` or `telefono` members.

So your code won't compile because the compiler can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Incidentally, although you declare the variable `int x;` in `introducir_datos()`, you don't initialize it anywhere, so you need to fix that too.

Comment: So i must type introducir_datos(struct agenda*)? im really sorry im very lost here.

Comment: @user3920364 I've updated my answer a bit. If you're having trouble understanding how arrays and pointers work, there are plenty of tutorials on this subject. Just search for [c pointers and arrays tutorial](http://google.com/search?q=c+pointers+and+arrays+tutorial) (or [apuntadores y arreglos en c](http://google.es/search?q=apuntadores+y+arreglos+en+c), perhaps?)